# get hashmap value from protected method java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am new in complicated concepts of java, and i also know that its not a difficult question, but I know i am doing some mistake, here is a method in my class, and i am extracting its values in my main method, but it shows `NaN`
this is method:

```
protected static Map<String, Double> getSlaMetrics(List<Vm> vms) {
        Map<String, Double> metrics = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        List<Double> slaViolation = new LinkedList<Double>();
        double totalAllocated = 0;
        double totalRequested = 0;
        double totalUnderAllocatedDueToMigration = 0;

    for (Vm vm : vms) {
        double vmTotalAllocated = 0;
        double vmTotalRequested = 0;
        double vmUnderAllocatedDueToMigration = 0;
        double previousTime = -1;
        double previousAllocated = 0;
        double previousRequested = 0;
        boolean previousIsInMigration = false;

        for (VmStateHistoryEntry entry : vm.getStateHistory()) {
            if (previousTime != -1) {
                double timeDiff = entry.getTime() - previousTime;
                vmTotalAllocated += previousAllocated * timeDiff;
                vmTotalRequested += previousRequested * timeDiff;

                if (previousAllocated < previousRequested) {
                    slaViolation.add((previousRequested - previousAllocated) / previousRequested);
                    if (previousIsInMigration) {
                        vmUnderAllocatedDueToMigration += (previousRequested - previousAllocated)
                                * timeDiff;
                    }
                }
            }

            previousAllocated = entry.getAllocatedMips();
            previousRequested = entry.getRequestedMips();
            previousTime = entry.getTime();
            previousIsInMigration = entry.isInMigration();
        }

        totalAllocated += vmTotalAllocated;
        totalRequested += vmTotalRequested;
        totalUnderAllocatedDueToMigration += vmUnderAllocatedDueToMigration;
    }

    metrics.put("overall", (totalRequested - totalAllocated) / totalRequested);
    if (slaViolation.isEmpty()) {
        metrics.put("average", 0.);
    } else {
        metrics.put("average", MathUtil.mean(slaViolation));
    }
    metrics.put("underallocated_migration", totalUnderAllocatedDueToMigration / totalRequested);
    // metrics.put("sla_time_per_vm_with_migration", slaViolationTimePerVmWithMigration /
    // totalTime);
    // metrics.put("sla_time_per_vm_without_migration", slaViolationTimePerVmWithoutMigration /
    // totalTime);

    return metrics;
}
```

I am trying to print its values by this code:

```
Map<String, Double> results = getSlaMetrics(vmList);
System.out.println("Overall Violations:" + results.get("overall"));
```

I know its a basic question but please dont mind.

Comment: Have you tried debugging through your code? What line does the error happen at?

Comment: no error just get NaN

Comment: Have you used debugger? NaN means that you some where in your code you executed 0.0 / 0.0

Answer (score 2):

Getting *NaN "Not a Number"* means we tried to divide zero by zero. Dividing non-zero number by zero will result to `-Infinity` or `Infinity`.
I would take a look at this line and make sure don't divide the number by zero.

> metrics.put("overall", (totalRequested - totalAllocated) /
>   totalRequested);

As mentioned by Ivan in the comment below, let's demonstrate several cases of `NaN`, `-Infinity` and `Infinity`

```
System.out.println(0.0/0.0);
System.out.println(0/0.0);
System.out.println(-1/0.0);
System.out.println(1/0.0);
```

It produces the following output:

```
NaN
NaN
-Infinity
Infinity
```

Comment: `Double.NaN` will appear only for `0.0 / 0.0` case. If you divide some non-zero number by 0.0 you will get either `Infinity` or `-Infinity`

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem here is not with the Map and its methods but it is with the code.
If you go through this code then the control is never going to the following

```
if (previousTime != -1) {
                double timeDiff = entry.getTime() - previousTime;
                vmTotalAllocated += previousAllocated * timeDiff;
                vmTotalRequested += previousRequested * timeDiff;

                if (previousAllocated < previousRequested) {
                    slaViolation.add((previousRequested - previousAllocated) / previousRequested);
                    if (previousIsInMigration) {
                        vmUnderAllocatedDueToMigration += (previousRequested - previousAllocated)
                                * timeDiff;
                    }
                }
```

so values assigned in the following assignment are zero

```
         totalAllocated += vmTotalAllocated;          //  zero
        totalRequested += vmTotalRequested;           // zero
        totalUnderAllocatedDueToMigration += vmUnderAllocatedDueToMigration;  // zero
```

Hence the following value in Map is 0.0/ 0.0 i.e. NaN

```
 metrics.put("overall", (totalRequested - totalAllocated) / totalRequested); 

   // Value in Map for Key "overall" is ==> 0.0 - 0.0/0.0 = NaN
```

So it's not a surprise if you get NaN in output.